# full background and non expected 1px border

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

I'm using the following code to render a full background, a box, header and footer. Everything works greats in all browser (ie8+, I don't care for ie7). But in ie8 a 1px border is rendered around the background. Why?

```
    <style type="text/css">

        /*
            start reset
            http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
        */

        html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
        h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
        a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
        del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
        small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
        b, u, i, center,
        dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
        fieldset, form, label, legend,
        table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
        article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
        figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
        menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
        time, mark, audio, video {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            border: 0;
            font-size: 100%;
            font: inherit;
            vertical-align: baseline;
        }
        article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
        footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
            display: block;
        }
        body {
            line-height: 1;
        }
        ol, ul {
            list-style: none;
        }
        blockquote, q {
            quotes: none;
        }
        blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
        q:before, q:after {
            content: '';
            content: none;
        }
        table {
            border-collapse: collapse;
            border-spacing: 0;
        }

        /*
            end reset
        */

        .header, .footer
        {
            position: fixed;
            z-index: 2;
            left: 0px;
            width: 100%;
            background: white;
            opacity: 0.4;
            filter: alpha(opacity=40);
        }

        .header
        {
            top: 0;
            height: 30px;
        }

        .footer
        {
            bottom: 0px;
            height: 30px;
        }

        .box
        {
            position: relative;
            float: right;
            z-index: 2;
            margin: 100px 100px 0 0;
            width: 300px;
            padding: 20px;
            background: white;
            -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 20px black;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 20px black;
            box-shadow: 0 0 20px black;
        }

        .background
        {
            position: fixed;
            top: -50%;
            left: -50%;
            width: 200%;
            height: 200%;
        }

        .background img
        {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            margin: auto;
            min-width: 50%;
            min-height: 50%;
        }

        p
        {
            font: 15px/2 Georgia, Serif;
            text-indent: 40px;
        }

    </style>

</head>

<body>

    <div class="header">
        Vestibulum erat wisi.
    </div>

    <div class="box">
        <p>
            Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sitamet, wisi. Aenean
            fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, erosipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus
            lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enimin turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent
            dapibus, neque idcursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna
            eroseu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsanporttitor,
            facilisis luctus, metus.
        </p>
    </div>

    <div class="footer">
        Vestibulum erat wisi.
    </div>

    <div class="background">
        <img src="http://mslove88.files.wordpress.com/2011/10/mountain.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
```

Comment: JSFiddle for those who want it: http://jsfiddle.net/NGqY4/

Answer (score 2):

Do you use a reset stylesheet?

Because it can be a body margin/padding setting. Every browser has is own default CSS stylesheet and a reset stylesheet 'resets' it all to 0 making them all the same.

First one in the Google results: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: Does it 'cut off' 1px of the header or is the header moved 1px down? (same for the left)

Comment: Not sure, but looks like it cuts off 1px.

Comment: You can meassure the pixels of the header's height (if you can see it, otherwise give it another color). Also try a body { overflow: visible; } (this should be set to 'auto' by default but you never know :). I remember that the procent values inherent from parents, so also try this: html, body { width: 100%; }. Can you post the CSS code of the body & header element (by using firebug or the chrome console)?

Comment: .header {
    height: 40px;
    top: 0;
}
.header, .footer {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 white;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0.4;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
}

Comment: And the 'body' element? Plus you can set the margin to 0 of the 'background img' class.

Comment: Try to play with the header and body element in FireBug or Chrome Console. I don't have acces to a Windows PC at the moment, so I can't help you further.

Answer (score 2):

Just place the following code on CSS inside `<style>` and I hope it will solve your problem.

`html { border:none; }`

Answer (score 1):

I am also faced the same problem in my site. So i give the values in negative points like as below. Try it. I do it for body section. You may try this for form, div also.

```
<body style="margin-top: -10px; margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 0px; padding: 0px;>
```

Comment: IE only makes problem for me. So i tried this and it works well. Try it.

Comment: Try it for div tag and form tag also

Comment: still there. I can't understand. IE doesn't makes sense.

Comment: Did you hav set any background image?

Answer (score 0):

Change your code like below. Try also on div, form, body tags one by one.

```
.background img
        {
            position: absolute;
            top: -5;
            left: -5;
            right: -5;
            bottom: -5;
            margin: auto;
            min-width: 50%;
            min-height: 50%;
        }
```